# How to check if an application got closed and returned to device application list using robotium?

Tags: android-activity, robotium, android

Is there any way to check whether an android application got closed and returned to device application list using robotium?

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way, however two ideas came to my mind.
First:

```
private boolean isApplicationClosed() {
    return solo.getCurrentViews().size() == 0;
}
```

Second (this may affect your application):

```
private boolean isApplicationClosed() {
    try {
        solo.clickOnScreen(100, 100);
    } catch (AssertionFailedError e) {
        if("Click can not be completed!".equals(e.getMessage().trim()) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```