# Android avd check if application is running

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, robotium, android-testing

is possible to verify if during a test the application is running or is been closed? I'm using Robotium as test automation framework.

Comment: Not clear what you are asking.  Are you writing two applications and one needs to determine if the other is running?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19808599/how-to-check-if-an-application-got-closed-and-returned-to-device-application-lis/19819014#19819014

Comment: @PeriHartman i'm writing a test for an application and i'd like to check during the test if the application is still running.

Comment: Sorry, that still isn't clear.  If the test program and the "application" are one and the same, then of course the app will be running when you test it.  You must be trying to say something else.

Comment: sorry, i didn't specified everything 'cause i do it usually. here (http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_android.html)  is well explained